# React Native KeyboardAvoidingView not working with ImageBackground

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have this code and for some reason KeyboardAvoidingView stopped working once I added ImageBackground. I am a little lost, does anyone have any good input?

```
    return (
        <View style={[styles().container, {zIndex:10000}]}>
             <ImageBackground style={{width: 500, height:700}} source={require("../../Components/assets/River.png")} resizeMode='cover'>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
                    <Box w={width} h={height}>
                        <Text style={styles().TextHeaders}>
                        Welcome back!
                        </Text>
                        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={'padding'} keyboardVerticalOffset={-63}>
                            <Box w={width} h={height/2.4} style={styles().LoginBox}>
                                <Stack fill center spacing={15}>
                                    <TextInput
                                        style={styles().TextInput}
                                        label="Username"
                                        value={username}
                                        onChangeText={username => setUsername(username)}
                                    />
                                    <TextInput
                                        style={styles().TextInput}
                                        label="Password"
                                        value={password}
                                        onChangeText= { password => setPassword(password)}
                                        secureTextEntry
                                        right={<TextInput.Icon icon="eye" />}
                                    />
                                    <Button style={styles().Button} mode="contained" onPress={() => {checkLogin()}}>
                                        LOGIN
                                    </Button>
                                    <Text style={styles().Link}>Forgot password?</Text>
                                    <Text >Don't have an account? <Text style={styles().Link} onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Register')}}>Register</Text> </Text>
                                </Stack>
                            </Box>
                        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                    </Box>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    )
```

```
    LoginBox: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 45,
        marginTop: '105%',
        left: 35
    },
```

This was working before I added the ImageBackground, so I have tried messing around with the KeyboardAvoidingView properties

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you say more about what working/not working mean in this context? Are there errors? Screenshots or mockups of what you have and what you want would be helpful.